# Unable to fetch tha last 30 days data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch the last 30 days posts from firebase and I am trying to **use the timestamp in the posts in order to do so.** But I am not able to fetch the data.

Kotlin Code:

```
var database:DatabaseReference=Firebase.database.reference
        database.orderByChild("timestamp")
        val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
                for(postSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children)
                {
                    if(postSnapshot.child("timestamp").value.toString().toInt()>Time.from(Instant.now().minusSeconds(30*24*60*60)).toString().toInt())
                    {
                        val Post = postSnapshot.getValue(PostsModel::class.java)
                        postsList.add(Post!!)
                    }

                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
                Timber.d("failed")
            }
        }
```

Firebase Data Structure:
[image: Firebase Data Structure]

Comment: "I am not able to fetch the data" is really hard to help with, and Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. If you run the code in a debugger, does it ever reach the `onDataChange`? If so, does it go into the `for` loop? If so, is the value it reads from `timestamp` what you expect? If so, is the value for 30 days ago what you expect?

Comment: No it does not go inside onDataChange

Comment: Please please be a bit more self-exploring, as Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. Does it reach into `onCancelled` then? If that doesn't happen either, is anything written into your app's logcat when you attach the listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring a listener, but you're not attaching it to the database. Until you call `addValueEventListener`, `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` , or `get()`.

I recommend studying the Firebase documentation on [reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data) as it shows how to do those.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition that the time must be more than a month ago, then you will produce a list of suitable data. The error can also be at another level that you did not provide (data organization or perhaps you did not connect a listener)

```
Firebase.database.reference
    .whereGreaterThan("timestamp", Calendar.getInstance().also { it.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1) }.timeInMillis)
```