# Firebase / Swift: Limiting a read to recent entries

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I load only the comments that have been made in the last 30 days?
I can limit the amount of comment which should be loaded to 10,20 or x.
But I don't see an option to say show me only the comments which where made in the last x days.

This is how I load my comments from Firebase Realtime Database right now. Also below you can see my Database structure. I do add a timestamp to my posts.

```
   func loadData() {
        
        activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
        let placeIdFromSearch = ViewController.placeidUebertragen
        
        // current date and time
        let someDate = Date()

        // time interval since 1970
        let myTimeStamp = Int(someDate.timeIntervalSince1970)
        
        let historyTimeStamp = myTimeStamp + 40000

        ref = Database.database().reference().child("placeID/\(placeIdFromSearch)").queryOrdered(byChild:"userTime").queryStarting(atValue: myTimeStamp).queryEnding(atValue: historyTimeStamp) as? DatabaseReference
        ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            
            let showDefaultCell = false
            
            guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            let newPost = importPosts(dictionary: dic, key: snapshot.key)
            guard let userUid = newPost.userID else { return }
            self.fetchUser(uid: userUid, completed: {
                self.table.insert(newPost, at: 0)
                self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
    func fetchUser(uid: String, completed: @escaping () -> Void) {
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("user").child(uid).child("userInformation")
        ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            let newUser = UserModel(dictionary: dic)
           self.users.insert(newUser, at: 0)
            completed() 
        }
    }
```

It looks like on Android there is something called [Firebase.database.reference.whereGreaterThan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70215800/unable-to-fetch-tha-last-30-days-data-from-firebase) but I can't find this on iOS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `orderByChild` and `startAt`

This allows you to order the comments by a field, such as `userTime`.

Try replacing

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child("placeID/\(placeIdFromSearch)")
```

with

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
      .child("placeID/(placeIdFromSearch)")
      .queryOrdered(byChild:"userTime")
      .queryStarting(atValue: currentTime)
```

In preparation for this, create a numerical constant `currentTime` that is the current time in the format used in the `userTime` entry.

More info at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have two questions. 1. Don't I need to use a wildcard between placeID/placeIdFromSearch and the child userTime? Because there is still an autogenerated ID. 2. How can I exactly tell only the last 30 days? By using currentTime -/+ the 30 days?

Comment: No. You have given a location, e.g. "placeId/here:pds:...". If you had asked for orderBy _Key_, it would order the items by the key such as "-NPegl...". But you have asked for orderBy _Child_, which means lookin in into the _trees_ of all the children (e.g. "-NPegl") and order by a _child_ value, such as "orderTime". It's a special syntax in Firebase which takes some time to get used to, don't worry! Firebase instructions online have a bizarre example about dinosaurs, that is supposed to explain this, but it didn't help me. I just had to try it, to understand.

Comment: The wildcard is implied, by the fact that we are using what Firebase elsewhere in its documentation calls `orderByChild`, i.e. skip a generation. Given _my father_'s identity as the root, order _me and my siblings_ by the heights of a particular child of each of us, e.g. each of us has a son called Bob, order me and my siblings by the age of our respective Bob's.

Comment: I updated my code like above but now it crashes and says "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" on following line: ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

Comment: What value did you create for currentTime? Try a value slightly smaller than the time number you showed for userTime.

Comment: I updated the code in my first post. I do use let someDate = Date() let myTimeStamp = Int(someDate.timeIntervalSince1970) for the current time. Maybe the issue is this part of code: as? DatabaseReference. As soon as I add it it crashes. But does not work without it.